# Is it possible to create an open-ended array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I was wondering if I could create an array without having to enter a value. I don't fully understand how they work, but I'm doing an inventory program and want my array to be set up in a way that the user can enter products and their related variables until they are done, then it needs to use a method to calculate the total cost for all the products. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Use an ArrayList.

This will allow you to create a dynamic array.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Here is an example/overview:

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_arraylist_example.xml

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. Instead of using a primitive type array, for example `new int[10]`, use something like the Vector class, or perhaps ArrayList (checkout API docs for the differences). Using an ArrayList looks like this:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("Item 1");
myList.add("Item 2");
myList.add("Item 3");
// ... etc
```

In other words, it grows dynamically as you add things to it.

Answer (score 1):

As Orbit pointed out, use ArrayList or Vector for your data storage requirements, they don't need specific size to be assigned while declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with the Java Collections Framework, which includes ArrayList as others have pointed out. It's good to know what other collection objects are available as one might better fit your needs than another for certain requirements. For instance, if you want to make sure your "list" contains no duplicate elements a HashSet might be the answer.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already told how to do it right. For completeness, in Java every array has a fixed size (length) which is determined at creation and never changes. (An array also has a component type, which never changes.)

So, you'll have to create a new (bigger) array when your old array is full, and copy the old content over. Luckily, the ArrayList class does that for you when its internal backing array is full, so you can concentrate on the actual business task at hand.